# $Z_3\times Z_3$ is not a cyclic group but $Z_3\times Z_5$ is

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For any $(x,y)$ belonging to $Z_3\times Z_3$ , $(x,y)^3 = (3x,3y)= (0,0)$ is the identity element. Again the order of $Z_3\times Z_3$ is $3\cdot 3=9$ therefore $Z_3\times Z_3$ cannot be generated by any $(x,y)$ belonging to $Z_3\times Z_3$. 
As $(3,5)=1 \implies Z_3\times Z_5$ isomorphic to $Z_{15} = \langle1\rangle$. Therefore $Z_3\times Z_5$ is cyclic. Please tell me if i am correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, and you can use the following for proving the case for each of your groups:

> $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, I.e., it is cyclic if and only if $m, n$ are relatively prime.

Since $\gcd(3, 3) = 3\neq 1$, $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3$ is not cyclic.

And as you note, $\gcd(3, 5) = 1$, and hence, $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_5 \cong \mathbb Z_{15}$ is indeed cyclic.

Comment: I came so close yet finally made a fool out of myself.

Comment: No, your reasoning for the first was fine. You are no fool! ;-)

Comment: Can we say if (m,n)=1 then the ring Zm x Zn isomorphic to the ring Zmn analogous to the groups.

Comment: I think may be we can because for the addition of the ring under which the ring is also an abelian group the statement is true. Now we have check the case of product .